# Git Cloning an exact copy of code submitted to GitHub as a pull request

Tags: git, github, version-control

## **Context:**

I use git to version-control an open-source repository I host on GitHub. Contributors to my repo submit pull requests to the master branch, and it is common for there to be a delay of a week or more between the time the PR is submitted, and the time I'm able to run independent testing on the code that was submitted with the PR. During this time, there are no guarantees that the branch submitted by my collaborator was frozen. So if a week or more were to pass, and I were to simply clone the branch of the repo from which the PR was submitted, there are no guarantees that I am actually cloning the code that would be merged to the main repo if I were to merge the PR on GitHub.

## **Question:**

How can I use git clone an exact copy of the code submitted as part of a GitHub pull request?

Comment: Thanks, @rottweilers_anonymous, I didn't know that. Do you happen to know where this behavior is documented?

Answer (score 1):

Pull requests are automatically updated to match the branch they refer to.

edit: You're right, here's a quote from the official documentation:

> After your pull request is sent, any new commits pushed to your branch
>   will automatically be added to the pull request. This is especially
>   useful if you need to make more changes.

https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/#sending-the-pull-request

Comment: Thanks @rottweilers_anonymous - I recognize this answer as definitive, and I'm happy to mark this answer as the Accepted Answer, but the link you provided appears to just be a link to some kind of random 1-1 interchange on GitHub, rather than proper documentation. If you provided a reference to the official documentation explaining this functionality, I'd consider this the officially accepted answer.